# Switching to https using docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud

Tags: http, docker-compose, https, nextcloud, onlyoffice

I am currently working with the docker-compose given by OnlyOffice which installs NextCloud with it preconfigured, but I'm not able to find how to switch it to HTTPS.
Has anyone already done it ?
Thanks

I tried to change ports in the docker-compose (I knew it would not work but why not)

Answer (score 0):

You could check [this branch](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud/tree/feature/ssl) with SSL corrections and the corresponding instructions which would help you to switch everything to https.